# Signtool.exe /dg /ds /di options and timestamping

Tags: digital-signature, code-signing, signtool, trusted-timestamp

We are working on optimizing the digital signing process using the signtool.exe digest options. So far the workflow looks like this:

1. Create the digest on the client: **signtool.exe sign /f cert /fd sha256 /dg . MyFile.dll**
2. Send **MyFile.dll.dig** digest to our signing server.
3. Sign digest on the signing server: **signtool.exe sign /f cert /fd sha256 /ds MyFile.dll.dig**
4. Send the signature **MyFile.dll.dig.signed** back to the client.
5. Create signature on the client: **signtool.exe sign /di .MyFile.dll**
6. Add a timestamp on the client: **signtool.exe timestamp /tr http://some_timestamp_server /td sha256 MyFile.dll**

Is there a way to perform timestamping on the signing server?

Comment: What prevents you from performing the timestamping on the signing server?

Comment: What is the command? signtool.exe timestamp … MyFile.dll? MyFile.dll is never sent to the signing server.

Comment: Why do you not send the MyFile.dll file to the signing server, which will apply the timestamp with the command you wrote in the question?

Comment: Because of the file size. It could be hundreds of megabytes. While .dig and .deg.signature files are really small, under 1K.

Comment: When I try to replicate this locally it would seem that I need a p7u file that is created at step 1. Do you have the same behavior?

Comment: @AlexI Right after 1st step, I do see digital signature tab in the properties panel of MyFile.dll. Is that normal? I was expecting the tab be visible after the last step.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to perform timestamping on the signing server?

No, not without transferring the entire file to your signing server. The timestamping is an operation applied directly to the file itself, so the file must exist locally. Your remote signing service only works because only the digest needs to be signed, not the full binary. However, as you pointed out you still need to ingest the signed digest locally using the `/di` signtool option.

What you *can* do is create a custom tool to programmatically sign and timestamp a file according to your requirements. See this Microsoft article for how to use `SignerSignEx2` function which supports timestamping.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/how-to-programmatically-sign-a-package?redirectedfrom=MSDN

You've may have already seen this, but I would also look at the [AzureSignTool](https://github.com/vcsjones/AzureSignTool) repo which uses the undocumented `SignerSignEx3` function to perform the signing using a callback. You could reasonably replace the Azure functionality with a call to some other custom signing service.

Comment: When I try to replicate this locally it would seem that I need a p7u file that is created at step 1. Do you have the same behavior? I assume this file contains the certificates in PKCS7 and then the .signed file contains the signature in Base64.  Would the last step be only merging them both?

Comment: I don't believe the .p7u file is needed, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking though. Are you referring to the time stamping as the last step?

Comment: Actually, the ingest step: signtool.exe sign /di .MyFile.dll. If you erase the p7u file from the directory where MyFile.dll then you will get an error from the signtool

Comment: so yeah.. what does this .p7u has.. and why is it important? anybody?

Answer (score 0):

I learnt this hard way after so many trial and errors. For those who land here, here is the answer. You don't need signing cert private key on system where you are time stamping. Once a file has signature, you can invoke signtool with timestamp option. It will add time stamp for the signature.